# how can use ruby in div html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have rails application in content.html.erb, I have this code
I want to assign data-url with cover.image_address which is variable.
this code not work how can use ruby in div html.

`<div class="product" data-type="magazine" data-popup="true"

    data-url= <% "assets/#{cover.image_address}" %> > 
          <%= image_tag(cover.image_address, 
            {:width => "76", :height => "107"}) %>
</div>`

Comment: When you say "not work", what does the resulting HTML actually look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the missing `=` in the asset call. Should be:

`<%= "assets/#{cover.image_address}" %>`

Comment: tnX alot , very bad mistake!!! tnX again